# Exception is not propagated to onError() when thrown from doOnSubscribe()

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

There is a `PublishProcessor` which calls `.doOnSubscribe(checkCondition)` operator to perform certain check. `checkCondition` is intended to throw `UnsupportedOperationException`, which then has to be propagated to the subscriber down the stream to `onError()` method. Instead, `UndeliverableException` is being thrown and process crashes.

```
publishProcessor
    .filter(() -> { // predicate })
    .observeOn(scheduler)
    .doOnSubscribe(checkCondition)
    .to((sourceFlowable) -> new FancyFlowable(sourceFlowable)))
    .safeSubscribe(subscriber);
```

Does anyone has idea what is going wrong here? Why exception thrown from `checkCondition` is not propagated to the `onError` of subscriber?

Comment: The observed behavior is due to a bug. Fix in [#5103](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5103).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with RxJava 2's `doOnSubscribe` operator. If the `onSubscribe` callback crashes, the `Throwable` at that point can be signalled via `onError` legally. I'll post a fix for this soon.

For now, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279543/exception-is-not-propagated-to-onerror-when-thrown-from-doonsubscribe#comment71725988_42280896) may be a workaround for you:

> `Observable.defer(() -> checkCondition ? error(...) : publishProcessor)`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because that does not make sense; doOnSubscribe runs before the observable chain has been initialized properly. Have you considered something like this?

```
if(checkCondition) {
  Observable.error(...).safeSubscribe(subscriber);
}
```

And then continue with the original code (sans doOnSubscribe).

Comment: Condition might change after Observable has been prepared and before subscriber subscribes, so checking condition upfront won't solve the problem.

Comment: Oooh, I know! `Observable.defer(() -> checkCondition ? error(...) : publishProcessor)`, and chain normally.